# PHP set Variable based on condition

Tags: php, oracle

I'm so sorry for the post title if it's not related with my question below. Confused how to give it.

Example I have this below data table:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID_FK | EMAIL_ADDRESS
001              | a@example.com
002              | b@example.com
001              | c@example.com
```

When I query it, is it possible to set like this:
if same DEPARTMENT_ID_FK then show it as variable combine value based on DEPARTMENT_ID_FK

```
while($dData = oci_fetch_array($q))
{
     $email = $dData['EMAIL_ADDRESS']; // I know when I echoing this variable, it will be like : a@example.comb@example.comc@example.com
}
```

What I want is on looping we can know if:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID_FK | EMAIL_ADDRESS
001              | a@example.com, c@example.com
002              | b@example.com
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let Oracle do the aggregation for you

Oracle 11

```sql
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID_FK, 
       LISTAGG(EMAIL_ADDRESS, ',') 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL_ADDRESS) AS EMAIL_ADDRESS
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID_FK
```

Oracle 10

```sql
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID_FK, 
       RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, EMAIL_ADDRESS, ',') 
           ORDER BY EMAIL_ADDRESS).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL(), ',') AS EMAIL_ADDRESS
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID_FK
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=546515b6a164a556f9c264bf4c2160aa) demo for both queries

Outcome:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID_FK | EMAIL_ADDRESS
-----------------+----------------------------
001              | a@example.com,c@example.com
002              | b@example.com
-----------------+----------------------------
```

---

Or just aggregate in php with a couple of loops and a conditional

```php
$agg = [];

while ($dData = oci_fetch_array($q)) {
    $dep = $dData['DEPARTMENT_ID_FK'];
    $email = $dData['EMAIL_ADDRESS'];

    if (isset($agg[$dep])) {
        $agg[$dep][] = $email;
        continue;
    }

    $agg[$dep] = [$email];
}

$result = [];

foreach ($agg as $dep => $emails) {
    $result[] = [
        'DEPARTMENT_ID_FK' => $dep,
        'EMAIL_ADDRESS' => implode(',', $emails),
    ];
}

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vHUWR)

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT_ID_FK] => 001
            [EMAIL_ADDRESS] => a@example.com,c@example.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DEPARTMENT_ID_FK] => 002
            [EMAIL_ADDRESS] => a@example.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi peterm, thanks for the answer but I got error like this: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. I'm using Toad

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using exactly? Did you change the name of the table?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10.0.2.5, Yes I have changed with my table name

Comment: `LISTAGG` is available since 11gR2. You can leverage `XMLAGG` instead in Oracle 10. See the updated answer.

Comment: I tried to run the query but got this error, ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB. Please help peterm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150686/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-peterm).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve your objective.

`$email = array();
while($dData = oci_fetch_array($q)) {
     $email[$dData['DEPARTMENT_ID_FK']] = (isset($email[$dData['DEPARTMENT_ID_FK']]) && $email[$dData['DEPARTMENT_ID_FK']] != '' ? ', ' : '').$dData['EMAIL_ADDRESS']; 
}
foreach ($email as $key=>$val){
    echo $key . ' => '. $val;
}`